# Cannot double-click/open docx files and file-shortcuts at desktop at Ubuntu19.4

Tags: 19.04, shortcuts, symbolic-link, hard-link

I recently upgraded to ubuntu 19.4. I used to ctrl+shift drag and drop files at desktop, in order to create shortcuts. At 19.4 some very useful functionalities are removed, I hope for good reason. You can still right-click/Create Link, or use the ln command.

The problem is that when a link is at desktop, I cannot double-click to open, nor right-click/open. Right-click/open with an other application works. Also, after right-click/Show In Files, which opens nautilus, you can just double-click to open.

Another thing, MS office files have the same behavior. Namely, I can double-click to open with Libre office, through nautilus, but when at desktop they only open with right-click/Open with an other application.

Any suggestions on how to double-click to open **file**-links at desktop?

Thank you

**Edit:**
The problem is resolved at Ubuntu 20.04.